Can't change the speed on bxSlider
I tried changing the speed but it seems to revert to 9s
https://viechem.blogspot.com/

mode:"horizontal",slideSelector:"",infiniteLoop:!0,hideControlOnEnd:!1,speed:85000,easing:"linear",slideMargin:10,startSlide:0,randomStart:!0,captions:!0,ticker:!1,tickerHover:!1,adaptiveHeight:!1,adaptiveHeightSpeed:18000,video:!1,useCSS:!0,preloadImages:"visible",responsive:!1,slideZIndex:50,wrapperClass:"bx-wrapper",touchEnabled:!0,swipeThreshold:50,oneToOneTouch:!0,preventDefaultSwipeX:!0,preventDefaultSwipeY:!1,ariaLive:!0,ariaHidden:!0,keyboardEnabled:!0,pager:!0,pagerType:"full",pagerShortSeparator:"
/
",pagerSelector:null,buildPager:null,pagerCustom:null,controls:!0,nextText:"Next",prevText:"Prev",nextSelector:null,prevSelector:null,autoControls:!1,startText:"Start",stopText:"Stop",autoControlsCombine:!1,autoControlsSelector:null,auto:!1,pause:4e3,autoStart:!0,autoDirection:"next",stopAutoOnClick:!1,autoHover:!1,autoDelay:0,autoSlideForOnePage:!1,minSlides:17,maxSlides:17,moveSlides:0,slideWidth:300,shrinkItems:!1,onSliderLoad:function(){return!0},onSlideBefore:function(){return!0},onSlideAfter:function(){return!0},onSlideNext:function(){return!0},onSlidePrev:function(){return!0},onSliderResize:function(){return!0}};t.fn.bxSlider=function(n){if(0===this.length)return
this;if(this.length>1)return
this.each(function(){t(this).bxSlider(n)}),this;var
s={},o=this,r=t(window).width(),a=t(window).height();if(!t(o).data("bxSlider")){var l=function(){t(o).data("bxSlider")||

I tried using useCSS:!1, but the speed becomes erratic, it will speed up and slow down.
Reducing the number of images I put on the slider slows it, but I need all of those images to show.

Please, create a [mcve]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
